# How can I reduce the weight of my javascript min file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, three.js, swiper.js

I have like one javascript file with different functions (it's weight is around 100kb) and some other javascript plugins: three.js (480kb), bootstrap modal.js and collapse.js (like 16kb), debouce.js (731b), swiper.js (87kb).

The thing is that I don't use all the functions nor the plugins in every page so I added something like `if($(selector).length)` before making any function call so I don't get any errors, but I think It would be better to have **one min file** with only the related functions and plugins for each page.

Let's say:

- **All the website require:** `general_functions()` and
- **Index require:** `three_js_related_functions()` + `swiper_js_functios()` + `gallery_functions()` + swiper.js + three.js + debounce.js
- **Store require:** `swiper_js_functions()` + swiper.js
- **Pages and singles may require:** `gallery_functions()` + `swiper_js_functions()` + swiper.js

I'm also worried to make it Scalable and Maintainable.

Should I keep using `if($(selector).length)` and a big javascript file or would it be better to create different files distributing my functions and a min file with every possible combination?

Comment: Sounds like a job for RequireJS - http://requirejs.org/

Comment: You should code how you like, within reason. It's all in how you deliver the final code. Requirejs will work. Another is to Grunt the files with remove logging and uglify, which is what I prefer. Whatever route you go, you can then also configure your server to serve the files as zipped on the fly. The browser will unzip them on-load automatically as long as your server is configured correctly.

Comment: @Keith.Abramo Thanks I will definitely try RequireJS.

Comment: @Radio I'm currently using CodeKit to minify and manage my SASS and JS, I found [this article](https://taupecat.com/blog/2014/01/17/codekit-and-grunt-and-gulp-oh-my/) and It suggests Glup instead of CodeKit or Grunt.

Comment: That's fine, just making sure you're doing that. I think I see what you're getting at now, where uglification/minification cannot process the native code down, you're looking for ways to be clever with syntax to reduce. requirejs is the way to go.